# Javascript onLoad File api event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi, html5-filesystem

I have a small snippet of code

```
<input type="file"  style="margin-left:10px" id="file"/>
```

and JavaScript snippet is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function compress(evt){
  console.log('coming here');
                   var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
                   var r = new FileReader();
               r.onload = function(e) { 
               console.log('coming here also');

               var contents = e.target.result;
        alert( "Got the file.n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn");  
      }

        }

      document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', compress, false);

</script>
```

In console I can see `coming here` but `r.onload` function is not working.
Can anyone please tell why its not working. I am using chrome latest version.

Comment: you are not calling any of the `readAs*` functions so your reader isnt reading anything and so nothing to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [readAs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) method, if your file type is image, do like:

```
var f = evt.target.files[0];
var imageType = /image.*/;
if (f.type.match(imageType)) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) { 
        var result = r.result;
        console.log(result);
    }
    r.readAsDataURL(f); 
}
```